# equal_range c++ element order

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I am using multimap's equal range in C++. In my case there can be multiple entries for the same key - thus multimap. I wonder if the returned iterator will deliver the items in the defined order or is it left to the implemeter of the STL. For example, I will insert in the multimap the keys A B C D E F C X Y Z C M N A etc.
and would like to know in which order the iterator will return me the atching keys. Order in which they have been inserted? last inserted first? not-defined?
I try to avoid storing extra info just to know the order. In my case it is plain C++, not even C++11. Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate keys will be inserted after the existing keys, so the order of elements will be maintained (see "Associative containers" in the language spec).

Comment: Hi 1201ProgramAlarm and thank you. Maybe I am blind but where

Comment: I am looking at N3690 (chapter 23?) and can't find anything relevant. I am aware about the multimap implementations unsing either RB tree or AVL tree. My understanding is that all storing/finding/ iteration in multimap is based on the provided "less" function that's why I  am puzzled with the given answer. My question is - is there a guaranteed order (which should be observed by all implementations) for the iterator equal_range elements since they all have the same value. Sorry if I missing your point. Regards, Victor

Comment: @user612514 In N4527, section 23.2.4 [associative.reqmts], table 101, description of `a_eq.emplace` and `a_eq.insert`.  (This is table 102 in N3242; I don't have N3690).

Comment: Thank you very much again for pointing out the precise location of the rules. I think just because of the volume of this material I have missed it. Regards, Victor